# React - Digit 0 is not saved to local storage all other digits are kept in sync

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, parseint

I am using [react-range](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-range) and local storage for my project I got a problem which intrigued me as I mentioned earlier I am using react-range the user controls the slider from 0 to 100 it looks like this

[image]

My problem is that if the user changes the value using the slider to zero (that is, 0), then the number 0 in the local storage will not be saved, but all other numbers from 1 to 100 work fine and are saved in the local storage

```
export default (Component) => (props) => {

  const ls = parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem('values'));
  const [someValue, setSomeValue] = useState(ls ? [ls] : [25]);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('values', someValue);
  });

  return (
    <SideBarContext.Provider value={{ someValue, setSomeValue }}>
      <Component {...props} />
    </SideBarContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I assumed that the problem lies in parseInt, which returns a string to an integer, then I looked on the Internet and it says that the digit 0 is also an integer, I can’t understand what the problem is

Comment: 0 is a falsy value. So `ls ?` will evaluate to false

Comment: The test in the `? :` operator is the problem. When `ls` is 0, it is `false` in the test. Use `ls != null` instead.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
const [someValue, setSomeValue] = useState((ls!==null) ? [ls] : [25])
```

Comment: Personally I'd use `!=` because that would also test for `undefined`, but this is correct.